# How to find the locations of all the trees in Minecraft?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

I am working on coding a bot for Minecraft in Java. The first step is to find trees in the world. I am using mcp-reborn (so basically the source code) but answers in Forge can also be useful to me. I am trying to find the locations of all the trees. Using a loop to keep branching off in all directions searching for logs is the first thing that came to my mind. The issue is, this is very inefficient and can take a very long time. I am thinking that since I have access to the world seed, I could try to get the locations of all the trees by regenerating just the trees. This does not sound like a good solution either, and even if it was, I have no clue how to implement something like that.

So my question is, what is the most efficient solution to getting the locations of all the trees in a Minecraft world (or few chunks around player)? Again, answers in MCP or Forge will both be useful to me. One important thing to note is my code **cannot** run during world generation; it has to find the locations of all trees *after* the world has completed generating. Here is an example of how the function that I am looking for would look:

```
public static List<BlockPos> getAllTheTrees(World world, long seed, ... whatever else is needed ...) {
    ...
    return ...
}
```

Thank you so much for your help! Have a great day ;)